# Como colocar legenda em um ImageView

Tags: android, imagem, android-layout

Gostaria de saber se é possível colocar legenda em uma `ImageView` parecido com o da imagem a baixo, se possível uma explicação ou material de estudo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 7):

Há várias formas de se realizar isso. Eis duas:

1- Desenhando todos os elementos (imagem e rodapé) manualmente no canvas, estendendo a classe ImageView e sobrescrevendo seu método onDraw()

```
public class ImagemComRodape extends ImageView {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //deixa a classe ImageView desenhar a imagem normalmente
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //desenha o rodapé (que aparecerá em cima da imagem)
        canvas.drawRect(...);
        canvas.drawText(...);
    }
}
```

2- Em vez de utilizar um ImageView, é possível criar um RelativeLayout, atribuir a imagem como sendo o background desse RelativeLayout, definir a largura e a altura do RelativeLayout conforme desejado, e por fim, acrescentar um TextView (com o texto da sua legenda) ao RelativeLayout, alinhando-o à parte de baixo do RelativeLayout.

Nos meus aplicativos eu utilizo a primeira solução, por envolver menos views.

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma que da pra fazer é colocar a imagem como background de um layout e dentro desse layout um textView. Ficaria assim:

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

a partir disso você consegue ajustar um fundo no texto pra ficar semelhante ao transparente da imagem que você colocou.

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo a dica que @Wakim colocou para mim nesta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15196/layout-de-imagens-dinamicamente-apos-foto-ser-capturada), você pode fazer assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="Legenda da imagem"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:background="#99000000" />
</FrameLayout>
```